# Convert Ether to Wei without web3

Tags: javascript

I don't want to load the web3 library, I do however want to convert Either to Wei, does anyone have a JavaScript function to share.

I don't mind loading a smaller library

Comment: Web3 is the most popular for this sort of thing, but you can try `ethereum-units` instead

Comment: One ether is 1e18 wei. HOWEVER you will need the JavaScript big number library to be able to use numbers this large without rounding errors.

Answer (score 4):

Just multiply the number of ether by 1e18 (or 10**18).  Done and done!

Comment: Is there is difference in performance of manually multiplying and using the web3 method ?

Comment: FTR you actually need to multiply with 1e18 (and not 10e18)

Answer (score 3):

Accourding to this [table](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide/blob/master/source/ether.rst#what-is-ether):

- Wei = 10^0 Wei
- Ada = 10^3 Wei
- Babbage = 10^6 Wei
- Shannon = 10^9 Wei
- Szabo = 10^12 Wei
- Finney = 10^15 Wei
- Ether = 10^18 Wei

1 Ether is 1^18 = 1000000000000000000 Wei.

1 Wei is 0.000000000000000001 Ether.

Answer (score 2):

In javascript it would be `wei = eth_amount*10e17`. Not `*10e18` . `e` counts as the `10` and `*10e18` would multiply your eth by one order of magnitude too many!